# Auth0 async await return session user

Tags: reactjs, promise, async-await, auth0

I have set up Auth0 using custom inputs with react and hooks.  I am trying to protect my routes so that the user directs where they are based on our API and what information is provided back from that.  In order to do that I am setting the user data inside of the setSession, but the item is coming back undefined/ has to do with `auth0Client.client.userInfo` not finishing before setSession function is done.

```
const setSession = async authResult => {

    const expiresAt = JSON.stringify(
      authResult.expiresIn * 1000 + new Date().getTime()
    )
    localStorage.setItem('access_token', authResult.accessToken)
    localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken)
    localStorage.setItem('expires_at', expiresAt)
    localStorage.setItem('auth', true)

    setAuthenticated(true);

    await auth0Client.client.userInfo(authResult.accessToken, (err, user) => {
      localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user))
      setUser(JSON.stringify(user));
    })
  }
```

I call setSession in handle authentication:

```
  const handleAuthentication = () => {
    console.log("auth0Client", auth0Client);
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        auth0Client.parseHash(async (err, authResult) => {
            if (authResult && authResult.accessToken && authResult.idToken) {
              await setSession(authResult);
              history.replace('/');
            } else if (err) {
              console.log(err)
              return err;
            }
        })
      }
  }
```

I have tried return the value and calling it this way instead:

```
await setSession(authResult).then(
            () => history.replace('/')
        )
```

Either way, the first time it accesses the route that I want it has a null value for user.

I have put a complete mock repo here.  You can create accounts and if you create extra accounts use the same email with +modifier/ example test+1@test.com

https://github.com/Sbphillips19/ManualAuth0Flow

I'm sure it's something simple, I have just tried probably 100 different ways over and over again and can't see it.

Comment: It seems unlikely that `auth0Client.client.userInfo()` returns a promise (since you are passing it a regular callback) and `await` only does something useful when you await a promise.  So, that `await` is probably not doing anything, which means that the promise that `setSession()` returns is also not waiting for completion.

Comment: @jfriend00 is correct.  I've used auth0 in the past for my company;  They had no intention of converting their callback SDK to promises.  You can however use a library like Bluebird to wrap callback functions to return Promises.  Let me know if you need assistance if you want to go that route.

Comment: That actually makes a lot more sense.  I’m still a bit confused as I have seen several posts dealing with some of the other issues I’ve faced like parse hash being called twice and I’ve seen people do this which unfortunately doesn’t work for me:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47620540/wrapping-auth0s-parsehash-function-in-a-promise

Also in the docs I’ve seen async await used several times.  Does that just mean it’s not doing anything, or are promises used in other areas just not with that specific call?  I will try out bluebird in the next day and get back with my findings!

Answer (score 1):

I'd give Jim and Jfriend00 the answer, but since it's a comment and I can't here is the answer using Bluebird:

```
   await new Bluebird(function (resolve, reject) {
    auth0Client.client.userInfo(authResult.accessToken, (err, user) => {
      if (err) return reject(err)
      resolve(user);
    })
    }).then(
        data => 
        {
            localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(data))
            setUser(JSON.stringify(data));

        }
    )
```

It looks like auth0 has talks about converting all their functions to be able to use async await, but for now bluebird will do!